# Multiple lists in one ListView

Tags: java, list, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I have a series of buttons that I would like the user to press in order to show a different list in the list view. Say, button one brings up list one. User adds a few items to list one and then presses button two to open list two; user then adds a few items to that list.

How would I go about having multiple list that share a single list view? Also, how would I have the data of one list be saved so when the user switches lists... they can switch back to the original and have their items still presented in the list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

[here is an example too](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129)

Comment: Sadly, no. I am looking for individual lists. Where as these parents are presented on the same list in the example. I'm thinking fragments will do the trick here. Just need to figure out exactly how. But... This is a good backup method in case I can't figure out how to do it the way I originally envisioned Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. just make sure you don't have two nested scrollable containers

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple lists stored in some type of array. A list could be used for each list, and then when you are setting the listview's adapter, pass the current list object. Of course, after each item is added during the adding process(when user is adding items) you would need to add the items to the list, and then reset the listview. And as long as you kept the lists in context the entire time they would not be GarbageCollected. Once the user is done with the lists, you would need to save the lists somehow, unless this is just a temporary context where everytime you revisit the page it shows the default value for the lists.